# Opening a hidden website window and downloading a file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

what I want to do is download (hidden) an image and open it and in the same time open a hidden website window. What I have is this:

```
powershell "@('url1','url2') | foreach{$fileName = $env:TEMP + (Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf);(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($_,$fileName);Invoke-Item $fileName}"
```

It worked once or twice, but now it only shows the cmd and closes itself and doesn't do anything anymore. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Are the files available on the server? Are the files downloaded properly?

Comment: I am testing this with a direct link to images from google. Nothing happens, doesn't download, doesn't open. I would like to just open one link and download a second one, cmd pops up and closes. It worked two days back, but only like once or twice, when I tested it on another computer and it didn't work at all.